# Animate HTML5 Progress Bar with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm trying to do a simple HTML5 progress bar. When a user clicks a button, I want it to (onclick) begin the animation so that it goes from 0-100 (full) in three seconds. It should be some really basic Javascript that I'm looking to throw in the head of my document.

Very similar to this: 
[HTML5 progress bar animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078726/html5-progress-bar-animation)

I just need it onclick instead of onload and with a button. It's just a standard HTML progress bar, so it looks like this:

```
<progress id="progress" value="0" min="0" max="100">0%</progress>
<input type="button" value="button" onclick="[make_progress_bar_go_from_0_to_100]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is this example from the question you posted: 
http://jsfiddle.net/526hM/

The part that attaches it to the onload is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    setTimeout(animator, updatesPerSecond);
}
```

All you need to do is attach this `animator` function to a button instead. To get the effect to happen in 3 seconds, update the timing variables.

HTML:

```
<progress max="200" value="0"></progress>
<button id="theButton">Start!</button>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var msecsPerUpdate = 1000/60; // # of milliseconds between updates, this gives 60fps
    var progress =  $('progress');
    var duration = 3;             // secs to animate for
    var interval = progress.attr('max')/(duration*1000/msecsPerUpdate);

    var animator = function(){
            progress.val(progress.val() + interval);
            if (progress.val() + interval < progress.attr('max')){
               setTimeout(animator, msecsPerUpdate);
            } else {
                progress.val(progress.attr('max'));
            }
        }

    $('#theButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        animator();
    });
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/526hM/28/

Comment: I can't get this to work and I'm not sure why. The code that was in the jsfiddle was inserted directly into the head of my document nested within script tags, however it's still refreshing my page and doing nothing. http://lrroberts0122.github.com/WDF/html5_form.html  Is a page with all of my code, including the inserted js. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you got jQuery on your page?
You can post your page if it's public accessible too.

Comment: You need jQuery included in your page, it is a library that makes it easier to code in JavaScript. All you need to do is include another script tag in your head **before** the script above:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Hmm. It's still not working. It keeps refreshing it. Updated version here: http://www.creativezeus.com/html5_form.html

Comment: That link doesn't work. I've added jQuery to my own version of your page and it works, only thing is the form into which you've put the html is being submitted by the pressing of the button (I didn't know `buttons` did that, TIL). To fix that you'd have to prevent the default action on click, as I've amended my code above.

Comment: http://www.creativezeus.com/html5_form.html  There's my source code. I still can't for the life of me figure out why. :( I had accidentally messed up the link before. This is the correct one now.

Comment: That's because you've merged the external jQuery `<script>` with the inline `<script>`; this doesn't work.
Here's my version of you file, which works: http://pastebin.com/QZgXRQnm

Comment: Aha! :) Thank you sir, you are amazing. And I appreciate helping me all this time. I'm new and just taking some of my HTML files I did in class and experimenting with JavaScript. Thank you for the help! =D